# How to import OpenCV in the Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, opencv

I made opencv dependency tag in the pom.xml like the following.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opencv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.8</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.lib.path}/opencv-348.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

And I added "private static" method in Java file like the following.

```
private static boolean _Initialized() {
    try {
        String libname = "C:/Windows/System32/opencv_java348.dll";
        System.load(libname);
        return true;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        log.warn(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then I added "public static" method like the following.

```
public static Boolean test() {
    if (_Initialized()) {
        log.info("CV*************" + _Initialized());
        log.info("CV*************" + Core.getVersionString());
    }
}
```

At last I made "GetMapping" method like the following.

```
@GetMapping("/opencv")
public ResponseEntity<?> getTestResult() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(OpenCVTest.test());
}
```

When I called API uri "/opencv", I got one success and one error like the following.

```
2019-12-02 19:09:13.516  INFO 6452 --- [ XNIO-1 task-28]  : CV*************true
2019-12-02 19:09:13.536 ERROR 6452 --- [ XNIO-1 task-28] : Internal Server Error

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
       org.opencv.core.Core.getVersionString_0()Ljava/lang/String;
```

For another test without maven, I made "main" method in the OpenCVTest.java like the following.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    if (_Initialized()) {
        log.info("CV*************"+ _Initialized());
        log.info("CV*************"+ Core.getVersionString());
    }
}
```

And then I ran the "main" method in the java independently apart from maven.
I got both of success like the following.

```
18:56:04.530 [main] INFO - CV*************true
18:56:04.537 [main] INFO - CV*************3.4.8
```

In a nutshell, *System.load(native dll)* always operates **successfully via the both ways**.

But *Calling native methods* of opencv.core.Core.* **fails only in the Maven project**.

Help me solve this problem, please.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution.

First, I changed  in the pom.xml like the following.
This jar comes from Maven Central Repository.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2-1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And then I added @Configuration java file like the following.

```
@Configuration
public class NativeLoadingConfiguration {
    static {
        nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared();
    }
}
```

At last I eliminated "System.load(native dll)" from Test.java file,

and eliminated "opencv_348.jar" and "opencv_java348.dll" from the system.

That's it.